# How to join tables from one database to another database

Tags: database, join

I need help on this.

I have **databaseA.tableA.columnA** and want to join with **databaseB.tableB.columnB**.

My columnB IS NULL and i need to extract the data from columnA and insert it into columnB.

The Where condition is column C in databaseA.tableA.columnA is the same with column C in databaseB.tableB.columnB

What is the most likely the SQL script will be?

**Thank you =)**

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: My dbms is microsoft sql server.